# Loop through results of sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 50 records.

In that table, I just added a column name Number (int). For each of those 50 records the current value is (NULL).

How can I make a simple query ( LOOP ) which will go through all those records (rows) and for each set the row number example (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables with `update`.  If you don't care about the ordering:

```
update t cross join
       (select @rn := 0) params
    t.number = (@rn := @tn + 1);
```

Alternatively, you could create a new table with an auto-increment column and load the data into that table.  That way, new records will also be assigned new numbers.